# MUI X DateRangePicker: does not provide an export named 'DateRange'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Hello all,**

I have an issue with the MUI X package, specifically the DateRangePicker. The documentation on the DateRangePicker is a bit unclear and I am unable to resolve this issue on my own. It throws out an error, which is the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module @mui_x-date-pickers-pro_DateRangePicker.js' does not provide an export named 'DateRange'
```

Sounds fair,  the module does not export it. However, then taking a look at the [example provided by MUI here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hpoj4v?file=/package.json:196-259), the implementation is the same. Including the required and installed packages;

```
import { DateRangePicker, DateRange } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/DateRangePicker';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';

const [value, setValue] = React.useState<DateRange<Date>>([null, null]);

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <DateRangePicker
            startText="Check-in"
            endText="Check-out"
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <TextField {...startProps} />
        <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> to </Box>
        <TextField {...endProps} />
    </React.Fragment>
    )}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

And the following is in my `package.json`;

```
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "latest",
"@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "latest",
"@types/react": "latest",
"@types/react-dom": "latest",
"date-fns": "latest",
"@types/react": "latest",
"@types/react-dom": "latest",
```

However the issue still occurs. And I have no clue why, since it's following the [documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/) and exact example. However, I can't get it to work. I tried it on a seperate project, with the same results. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the documentation isn't correct on this one. DateRange is exported from @mui/x-date-date-picker-pro

```js
import { DateRange } from "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro"
```

[Another example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4ibm45?file=/demo.tsx) uses the import as follows:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { DemoContainer, DemoItem } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/demo';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DateRangeCalendar } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/DateRangeCalendar';
import { DateRange } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro';

export default function DateRangeCalendarValue() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<DateRange<Dayjs>>([
    dayjs('2022-04-17'),
    dayjs('2022-04-21'),
  ]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DemoContainer components={['DateRangeCalendar', 'DateRangeCalendar']}>
        <DemoItem label="Uncontrolled calendar">
          <DateRangeCalendar
            defaultValue={[dayjs('2022-04-17'), dayjs('2022-04-21')]}
          />
        </DemoItem>
        <DemoItem label="Controlled calendar">
          <DateRangeCalendar
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
          />
        </DemoItem>
      </DemoContainer>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to install:**

```
npm install @mui/lab
```

**How to import:**

```
import DateRangePicker from '@mui/lab/DateRangePicker';
```

Answer (score 0):

npm i @mui/x-date-pickers

try installing this package. it worked for me